# How to force mariaDB to use index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, explain

I'm trying to execute a SQL Query. Unfortunately it does not use the index and instead does a table scan.

I've already created the following indeces:

- PRIMARY($phone, $$fc_date)
- idx $$fc_status_detail
- idx $$fc_date
- idx $$fc_status
- idx $$phone

Additionally I've duplicated the table, but this also did not provide any useful results.

This is the table structure:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| $id                | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| $created_date      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $phone             | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| $source            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Orga               | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Anrede             | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Vorname            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Zuname             | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Strasse            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PLZ                | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Ort                | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Geburtsdatum       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Email              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Zeitschrift        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Herkunft           | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Zeitschrift_Titel  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| telefon            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Stornogrund        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Storno             | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Telefonnummer      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Postleitzahl       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Geburtsjahr        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$fc_task          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$fc_user          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$fc_date          | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| $$fc_status        | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| $$fc_status_detail | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| $$qc_task          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$qc_user          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$qc_date          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$qc_status        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $$qc_status_detail | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $call_duration     | smallint(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| $call_attempts     | smallint(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    count(*) as total,
    CONCAT(case when c1.$$fc_date < 240 then "short" else "long" end, "/", c1.$$fc_status, "/", c1.$$fc_status_detail) as ergebnis,
    sum(case when c2.$$fc_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end)/ count(*) as c2_succes_rate
FROM
    contacts c1 FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY),
    contacts_copy c2
WHERE
    c1.$phone = c2.$phone
    and c1.$$fc_date < c2.$$fc_date
group by
    ergebnis
```

This is the result:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                | key     | key_len | ref           | rows    | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | ALL  | PRIMARY                                                      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 2017450 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ref  | PRIMARY,contacts_copy_$phone_IDX,contacts_copy_$$fc_date_IDX | PRIMARY | 402     | nmv.c1.$phone |       1 | Using where                     |
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

As you can see in row 1, though it recognizes the PRIMARY key, it does not use it. The problem is that it scans 2 Mio. rows and the query lasts at least 5 minutes.

Can anybody please explain, what the problem might be?

Comment: can you provide the table definitions please? it would be my impression that you're trying to create the index on the fly and that's what's taking up your time. Also without those it's really hard to "debug" queries

Comment: I've included the structure into my post.

Comment: As we do not need transactions, I've already switched from InnoDB to MyISAM Engine, but this did not help. I've increased the 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' to '5G', but this did not help either.

Comment: have you tried using `JOIN contacts_copy c2 ON c1.$phone = c2.$phone and c1.$$fc_date < c2.$$fc_date` instead of the where?

Comment: I've changed the FROM clause to (`contacts c1 JOIN contacts_copy c2 ON c1.$phone = c2.$phone and c1.$$fc_date < c2.$$fc_date`) and removed the WHERE clause completely. possible_keys are now (`PRIMARY,idx_telefon,idx_fcdatum`), but it does not choose them.

Comment: don't know how mariadb works to be honest, haven't used it or mysql in ages, am a postgresql user, but the way I design my databases `ergebnis` would be a column in itself and it would be populated/updated by triggers so I'd never calculate that at query time, might also be indexed (depending on your data). My guess would be since that field is so complex it has to create a temporary table just to be able to remember it.

Comment: It's not the `ergebnis`. Even if I change the query to the following: `EXPLAIN SELECT
 count(*) as total
FROM
 contacts c1 JOIN contacts_copy c2 ON c1.$phone = c2.$phone and c1.$$fc_date < c2.$$fc_date`, it still does not use the index of table `c1` aka `contacts`.

Comment: May it be a problem of the columntype `varchar(100)`?

Comment: maybe, but most likely you could convince mariadb to use the index if it's properly done, could you maybe make a fiddle somewhere? I'm sure more people would help if it was easier for them to test their theories

Comment: I've created a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vA3KtQFvZRQgeCBzdvR7sv/1

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vA3KtQFvZRQgeCBzdvR7sv/2 - this is the closest I got, with ergebnis as a field, and an index on it, it will use the index, I think your problem is that it needs an index on a calculated field which it doesn't have yet... I also dropped the join since I didn't understand the need for it (might be wrong here)

Comment: *"Can anybody please explain, what the problem might be?"* "Using temporary; Using filesort" pretty sure MySQL/MariaDB would have to made a disk based temporary table for 2017450 expected records that's way your run time is 5 minutes..

Comment: @xception Some background about the table: The table contains information about phone calls made within a call center. Every row is one specific call at a given point in time. I would like to find out two ore more consecutive calls to a specific phone number, that's why I use the self join.

Comment: @MarkoSeidenglanz see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) can you provide example data and expected results.. Maybe there is better rewrite for your query which have the same results but better performance.. Also we have to know your MySQL version as it is more easy in MySQL 8.0 to get consecutive records.. We also can test the optimize better as we have data optimizer plans can change depending on data sizes..

Comment: @MarkoSeidenglanz you should have put the actual requirement inside the question; in the future, try remembering that next time you ask a question.

Comment: The table is only for statistics. It doesn't need to have transactions and it will only seldom be updated. It's just a collection of call records made over some years and now we want to analyze the data. So I exported the data from Appengine Datastore and created that table. The query, that I want to create is as follows: Show me all consecutive calls to any number. After that I want to classify the first calls into short (<240 seconds) and long (>240 seconds) calls and I want to know, which result the calls had. Additionally I want to know the success rate of the second call.

Comment: what if there were more than 2 calls to a number?

Comment: Indeed that happens, but we leave that out for simplification.

Comment: please add anything relevant discussed in the comments to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using InnoDB, correct?  InnoDB secondary keys (such as `INDEX(phone)`) implicitly include the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  So, the index is effectively a BTree of `(phone, fc_date)`.

Next, let's notice that another column is needed from `c2`:  `fc_status`.  So, the Optimizer looked at the two ways to run the query.  First, note that either approach has the optimal columns in the index, and they are in the optimal order.

Plan A:  Use the index, then bounce back and forth between the index and the data.

Plan B:  Do a table scan, which won't need the back and forth.

The Optimizer correctly picked B.

You can have a better index, and the Optimizer will be very likely to pick it.  And it will be faster:

```
INDEX(phone, fc_date, fc_status)  -- in this order
```

This is "covering" in that all the needed columns are present.  Hence, there won't be any back and forth.

I need to criticize `VARCHAR(100)`.  This is potentially really bad for dates in that, depending on the format, they may not sort correctly.

Names are probably never 100 characters; emails could be longer.  Etc.  4 phone numbers?  What's up?

Comment: Really liked how you explained it (the index part)! As for why everything is varchar I think he was just too lazy to convert, after all even in the example query he compares the `$$fc_status` field with `'success'` but he could've just had a bool for success in the table instead. He's probably just starting working with databases and hasn't learned yet that using proper data types is faster and results typically in a smaller database. Let's not scare him yet with rough language, he's new!

Comment: This answer really helped to increase my understanding in table design. Unfortunately the query did not speed up using the combined INDEX(phone, fc_date, fc_status). I've imported everything to BigQuery. That solved the issue.

Comment: @MarkoSeidenglanz - Did you also remove `FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)`.  My take on "index hints":  "They may help today, but may make things worse tomorrow."

Comment: The problem was not because of the index, it was because of bad data. There were a lot of rows with `$phone=""`, which blow up the whole query.